# I need to compare values from two lookup activities in azure data factory and use them in a query but the query isn't working correct

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-data-factory

[image: i used another code but it didn't worked too]I tried this code

```
@select * from carrs.refernce_value where formatDateTime(activity('lkp_modified_Date').output.firstrow.MODIFED_DATE) >= formatDateTime(activity('lkp_watermarkvalue').output.firstrow.watermarkvalue)
```

but it was not taking the query as correct one and it is throwing an error
[image: this was the error i am getting]

Comment: please design your query and let me know if any errors in using it in the query activity. Or you can share the outputs of the two lookup activity and share some details on what you are trying to achieve, so that I can suggest

Answer (score 0):

What you have now looks like below.

Expression:

```
@select * from carrs.refernce_value where formatDateTime(activity('lkp_modified_Date').output.firstrow.MODIFED_DATE) >= formatDateTime(activity('lkp_watermarkvalue').output.firstrow.watermarkvalue)
```

SQL equivalent:

```
select * from carrs.refernce_value where 2021-10-27 >= 2021-10-28
```

basically you are just comparing two date time values where as you should compare a column in the table against a timestamp you lookup

Assuming you would get a right value from `activity('lkp_modified_Date').output.firstrow.MODIFED_DATE` and design query you can try in the below format after that.

**Note:** I have used a sample query as example.

```
@{concat('select * from carrs.refernce_value where col1 >=', formatDateTime(activity('lkp_watermarkvalue').output.firstrow.watermarkvalue))}
```

Comment: Yeah i tried it from lookup i am getting correct value but it is showing error like this

Comment: Failure happened on 'Source' side. ErrorCode=SqlOperationFailed,'Type=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Common.Shared.HybridDeliveryException,Message=A database operation failed with the following error: 'An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected, near 'T16:'.',Source=,''Type=System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException,Message=An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected, near 'T16:'.,Source=.Net SqlClient Data Provider,SqlErrorNumber=4145,Class=15,ErrorCode=-2146232060,State=1,Errors=[{Class=15,Number=4145,State=1,

Comment: Message=An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected, near 'T16:'.,},],'

Comment: Syntactically the query structure I have provided will work without error, but the issue is you have two different lookups from two different tables (i guess mostly) so , this query should contain join. Since you are not using join it is throwing that error

Comment: basically you are just comparing two date time values `formatDateTime(activity('lkp_modified_Date').output.firstrow.MODIFED_DATE) >= formatDateTime(activity('lkp_watermarkvalue').output.firstrow.watermarkvalue`   where as you should compare a column in the table against a timestamp you lookup